# Font 'Times New Roman' does not support style 'Regular'

Tags: .net, winforms, fonts, argumentexception

Anybody hear of this one? *System.ArgumentException: Font 'Times New Roman' does not support style 'Regular'.*

I've got a WinForms app that is deployed via ClickOnce. For some reason a number of users are getting this error. I can see getting this error because of picking a non-standard font, but Times New Roman, Regular? Is there a service pack or something that people need?

I would love to hear from anybody that has figured out a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution that seems to work is moving the font file to another directory, then reinstalling it (as explained further in http://www.binaryfortress.com/Forum/index.php?topic=691.0)

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick response! I was hoping for a simpler fix. Perhaps a click and go kind of solution.

Answer (score 11):

The link in the answer at binary fortress no longer works.
I had this issue with "Font 'Arial' does not support style 'Regular'" after uninstalling software. Managed to fix by reinstalling the font from the windows font folder:
Hit Start->Run 
c:\windows\fonts\arial.ttf

This brings up a window which has an install option at the top. Hit install.

Thank you to http://writeyouare.wordpress.com/2010/09/25/windows-7-fix-fonts-bold-italics/

Comment: Yes, reinstalling the font resolved similar issue I had when trying to open log files in Log Expert

Answer (score 1):

Re-installing the font worked for me. It seems some reorganization of some network folders triggered the problem because I had installed the font from that location and the registry was still pointing to the old location.