# Font 'Courier New' does not support style 'Regular' in Liquid XML

Tags: liquid-xml

When I start Liquid XML Studio I get the error

> Font 'Courier New' does not support style 'Regular'

At this point the application closes, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get this error if the Courier New font is not installed, or is corrupt, on your Windows O/S.

To correct this: 
1. Navigate to: 'Start->Settings->Control Panel->Fonts'
2. Look for the 'Courier New' font file (cour.ttf) 
3. If the file exists, double-click it and you should see sample of the font in use. 
4. If the file does not exists or is corrupt, you will need to copy it to your system, navigate to 'Start->Settings->Control Panel->Fonts' and select 'File->Install New Font...'

Note: You may also see this error may also occur for other corrupt or missing fonts.

Also See [Font 'Times New Roman' does not support style 'Regular'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245877/font-times-new-roman-does-not-support-style-regular)